# CloudFormation: Fn::GetAtt: not working for Endpoint.Address on AWS::RDS::DBInstance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

When I try to update or create a change set for a stack which uses `Fn::GetAtt: Database.Endpoint.Address` (where `Database` is the logical name of an `AWS::RDS::DBInstance` resource), the attempt fails with `Template error: every Fn::GetAtt object requires two non-empty parameters, the resource name and the resource attribute`.

This appears to be because CloudFormation decodes the YAML into the following JSON:

```
[
  'Database',
  'Endpoint',
  'Address'
]
```

This is clearly three parameters when it ought to be two. Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 4):

`Fn::GetAtt` expects an array with two parameters.  `!GetAtt` allows you to use the dot notation you are trying.

Either of these should work for you:

`Fn::GetAtt: [ "Database", "Endpoint.Address" ]`

`!GetAtt Database.Endpoint.Address`

Resources:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html

Comment: Unfortunately, for no reason I can divine, neither of those are working. I have a support ticket raised with AWS and I will update this post with any findings.

Comment: can you post a more complete version of your CF template? perhaps there is some sort of spacing/nesting function issues.

Comment: also would be good to know if you are getting the same error or a different error now

Answer (score 2):

Recommend trying the [CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/) in [VSCode](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cfn-lint-visual-studio-code) to see some of these errors inline while authoring templates along with autocompletion and documentation links:

[image: Visual Studio Code extension]

Try switching the syntax to [`!GetAtt Database.Endpoint.Address`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might be using it within a linux/unix statement and missing something in the syntax like a comma(,) or brackets([)

Example -
Here it is expected to put a comma(,) after !GetAtt Database.Endpoint.Address. If you miss this then Linter won't give an error as it is within linux script context and Cloud Formation will not give the correct error message.

"       wp core config --dbname='", !Ref DatabaseName, "' --dbuser='", !Ref DatabaseMasterUsername, "' --dbpass='", !Ref DatabaseMasterPassword, "' --dbhost='", !GetAtt Database.Endpoint.Address, "' --dbprefix=wp_ --allow-root\n",